# Correct way of saying 'I did not see people in the library'

Tags: grammar

人々をライブラリで見なかった。

Is this the correct way of writing 'I did not see people in the library'? I'm not 100% with the particles but 'wo' seems right attached to people.

I use ライブラリ just for the sake of attaching a location.

Comment: FYI, Japanese for "library" is 図書館【と.しょ.かん】.

Comment: @senshin is raiburari just modern equivalent? or i am totally wrong?

Comment: I think ライブラリ is used primarily for [libraries used in computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)) (like modules, etc.). 図書館 or 図書室 are for [libraries in the usual sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library) (either a separate institution or a small library inside a bigger building).

Comment: "Library" things set aside, I would say そこでは誰も見かけなかった for "I did not see people there."

Answer (score 4):

Natural ways to say it would be:

> 「[図書館]{としょかん}で人を(or は)見かけなかった。」
>
> 「図書館では、ほとんど人を(or は)見かけなかった。」

見かける ＞ 見る

「見る」 is not incorrect, but 「見かける」 is the more natural word choice.

Basically, no one would say 「ライブラリー」 to refer to a public library.  The word is 「図書館」.

「人々」 sounds "translated".  「人」 is the word to use here.